# How to Update a SharePoint Document library field in webapi using system.net.httpwebrequest

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, asp.net

I have written the code using authentication token from azure, I am able to get the data from sharepoint library but when updating , its throwing 400 error. Below is the code piece for reference.

```
                          string reqUrl = string.Format(DataApiUpdateData, sharepointSiteUrl, listname, j["ID"]);
                            var payload = new JObject
                            {
                                ["__metadata"] = new JObject { ["type"] = "SP.Data.MainDataListItem" },
                                ["TestText"] = "Some comments goes here"
                                
                            };
                            string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
                            string response2 = TokenHelper.UpdateAPI(reqUrl, content);
```

UpdateAPI call:

```
   public static string UpdateAPI(string url,string content)
    {
        string response = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            //Call to get AccessToken  
            string accessToken = GetSharePointAccessToken();
           
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);

            //Call to get the REST API response from Sharepoint  
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            endpointRequest.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
            endpointRequest.Method = "POST";
            endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
            endpointRequest.MediaType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
            endpointRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            endpointRequest.Headers.Add("IF-MATCH", "*");
            endpointRequest.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", GetRequestDigestValue());
            endpointRequest.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
            Stream dataStream = endpointRequest.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();                
            System.Net.WebResponse webResponse = endpointRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
            response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            return response;


            //New




        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```